# Can't get the WebView to remove the margin from body

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm trying to work out why my *WebView* app insists on keeping the margin on `body`. Here is my CSS:

```
* { 
    margin: 0; padding: 0; 
}
body, html { 
    margin: 0; padding: 0; 
}
iframe { 
    border: 0px 
}
body {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin:0px;
}
```

...and here is what I see: (the top and left both have a visible 8px margin around it)

[image]

..and here is what I see in the DOM:

[image]

I'm baffled as to why its showing `margin: 8px`, even when I've specifically told it NOT to have a margin on *, **body** and **html**.

I must be missing something silly - but I can't for the life of me find it.

Interestingly, if I check the page via a browser, the margins are fine:

[image]

It literally seems to be an issue with Android's WebView, verses a general CSS cross browser issue.

Comment: Are you sure your layout file does not have a margin or padding?

Comment: Given that this is the order in which they are applied **1.Browser default 2. External style sheet 3. Internal style sheet (in the head section) 4.Inline style** and that you also have display changed to `block`, it is very likely you overwrite them somewhere in 3 or 4

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm 100% sure I don't have a margin anywhere. The page content consists of: 1) header 2) content inside `body` 3: <style> tag, with the above in, 4) footer . There are no external CSS stylesheets/rules anywhere... which is whats baffling me so much

Comment: @RaduIonescu - I just updated my OP. I tested the page from a browser, and it works fine. Its as soon as its put inside the WebView part of Android, that this random 8px padding arises

Answer (score 0):

Ok, well I would never have thought of this to start with. The problem seemed to be with the fact that Android/PhoneGap/whatever, didn't like the fact I was using an inline style:

```
<style>
...
</style>
```

Instead, it wanted me to put all the CSS into a proper .css file, and then link it via:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css">
```

What a waste of my time - but at least its working now!